# A way to modify class (and general assembly) data at build time

Tags: c#, code-generation

This thing I want to do might not even be worth doing but I thought it would be cool.

So what I want to do is to have some code that runs when my project is building (not only when compiling), and adds stuff to my classes based on things like attributes and general code analysis. What I want to do is have dynamically generated fields/properties that are usable through intellisense, but not visible in the actual source.
The reason for that being that I might potentially want to generate a lot of them, and outputting them to source would turn into a mess very quickly.

The potential possibilities of a system like that would be stuff like vector swizzling.

Is there maybe a library of some sort for that that I could just plug my generation code in? If not, what would be the best way to approach this, if there is any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most visible example of this is done by Microsoft for XAML files. During the build, a C# source file is created for each XAML file and placed in the `obj/Debug` or `obj/Release` folder. In addition to that, the MSBuild `.targets` file where the relevant tasks are defined is specially configured to tell Visual Studio that the generated files are required for proper IntelliSense support, which means you don't actually have to explicitly build the project in order for IntelliSense to allow items declared in XAML to be used in C# code elsewhere in the project.

This is *exactly* the method I use for generating code for ANTLR grammar files during a build. You can see a complete example with a build task assembly and custom `.targets` file here:
https://github.com/antlr/antlrcs/tree/master/AntlrBuildTask

You should be aware that some 3<sup>rd</sup> party extensions for Visual Studio completely replace the IntelliSense support with their own implementation of code completion. Some of these extensions are known to not support the MSBuild IntelliSense extensibility features required for this to work with custom code generators. If you run into problems with IntelliSense and have any extensions installed, you may find that removing the extensions completely resolves the problems.

Comment: That sounds great! I'm so glad that a feature like this is supported without third party stuff being needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile code by the class CSharpCodeProvider/ICodeCompiler/CompilerParameters when application run.